# CSS - Genesis (Bootstrap) Column Classes

Tags: css, wordpress, class, genesis

I have a widgetized home-page for a WordPress Genesis theme - Outreach Pro.

I am having troubles with the margins on the two “About” widget areas (second & third) on the top row lining up with the third (Friends) & forth (Donate) widget areas on the second row.

Not sure if I need another DIV to make these columns the same width as the third (Friends) & forth (Donate) widget areas on the second row.

http://176.32.230.7/tavistockparishchurch.org/

Comment: I'd say you need to divide up the columns a bit more. First create a first and second row and then split those into half columns each, then put your containers in and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have lot of column classes inside columns so to get it right I had to use very specific rules to target those dives without effecting others. Please try following sample styling codes to control margins of above ABOUT widget areas to match the width of below areas:

```
.home .one-half .one-half.first .widget-1{ margin-right:8px}
.home .one-half .one-half.home-top .widget-greeen { margin-left:5px}
```